# Preg_match cuts last zeros from some numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I think it only happens when I write a regex. I have a simple regex to validate a set of pagination numbers, that later will be submitted to database, like `5`, `10`, `25`, `50`, `100`, `250` example:

```
/all|5|10|25|50|100|250/
```

When I perform a test, my regex above cuts `0` only from numbers *50, 100* and *250* but not from `10`!!?

Online example:
http://viper-7.com/IbKFKw

What am I doing wrong here? What am I really missing this time?

Comment: Thank you very much for correct answers but most of all for detailed explanations and helping to learn!! Deep respect to both of you!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because in the string `50`, the regex first matches `5`, which is valid. In the string `250`, the regex first matches `25`, which is valid and ends here.

You might try adding anchors:

```
/^(?:all|5|10|25|50|100|250)$/
```

This forces the regex to match the whole string, and hence, return the correct match you are looking for.

Comment: It works, Jerry! You're right! Can't believe it's so simple! You're becoming my personal regex guru!! Many thanks again!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev The name's 'Jerry' xD Thank you, but I think that I still have a long way to go to become a regex guru ^^

Comment: I fixed it, sorry, Jerry!!

Answer (score 7):

The alternatives are tried from left to right, so matching `5` takes precedence over `50`. But there's no `1` to cut off the `0` from `10`. You can simply reorder them:

```
/all|250|100|50|25|10|5/
```

Alternatively, add the `0` optionally to the relevant alternatives (and since `?` is greedy, the `0` will be matched if present):

```
/all|50?|100?|250?/
```

or

```
/all|(?:5|10|25)0?/
```

If this is not for matching but for validation (i.e. checking against the entire string), then go with Jerry's suggestion and use anchors to make sure that there are no undesired characters around your number:

```
/^(?:all|5|10|25|50|100|250)$/
```

(Of course inside `(?:...)` you could also use any of my above patterns, but now precedence is irrelevant because incomplete matches are disallowed.)

Comment: It works! You're right! I didn't know about precedence takes place here!